# Is Tomcat backward compatible?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I have few .WAR files that run on a tomcat 5.5 instance. So probably they would be Servlet Specification 2.3 or something not sure.

And I also have a new .WAR that is built with Servlet Spec 3.0 and needs tomcat7.

So my question is.. **Can I deploy the old tomcat 5.5 .WARs in the tomcat7 instance?**

So this way I'll have only **ONE** tomcat instance running. i.e. a Tomcat 7 that runs old and new WARs as well. Is this practical ?

**Edit::**
**And how can I make tomcat7 run these old tomcat 5.5 applications, if at all this is possible ?**

Comment: What is your Java version...?

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Right now the server where the I am suppose to deploy these WARs is a Unix machin. I am new to unix, I dont know the Java version but I will anyways be upgrading it java 1.7

Comment: check with "java -version" in your terminal, and mke sure to check it is Orcle java or Open java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,it should have the minimum tomcat version as per the guidelines.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a updated Java version (5+) for development, It should be working fine with the Tomcat version 7. So it should support your WAR and provide the backward compatibility.

**If migrating:**
If you check the tomcat migration guide from version 5.5 to 6.0, there are couple of upgrades to do a proper migration according to the migration guide mentioned 
[HERE](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-6.html)

and also a minor changes from 6.0 to 7.0 of Tomcat.

So it clearly talks about the Java version that you use, and must be minimum of Java 5.